# Не меняется значение поля в структуре

Tags: golang

Записываю новые значения полей так:

```
func (b *Block) Write(addr, info int) {
    b.Addr = addr
    b.Info = info
    b.IsChange = true
    fmt.Println("write", b)
}
```

Вывожу значения после того как изменил значение ("write") и в самом конце ("result"). Значения не меняются

```
write &{1 25 true true}
result {7 44 false false}
```

Полный код тут https://play.golang.org/p/_48M0RbVGV

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы дважды совершили одну и ту же ошибку.

```
for _, block := range *c {
    if block.Addr == addr {
        return &block
    }
}
```

Здесь вы возвращаете адрес переменной цикла вместо адреса значения в слайсе. Если переделать `search` и `replacement`, чтобы те возвращали адрес значения в слайсе, например

```
func (c Cache) search(addr int) *Block {
    for i := range c {
        if c[i].Addr == addr {
            return &c[i]
        }
    }
    return nil
}
```

получаем

```
result {1 25 true true}
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/E8jSHEuJtj.